# polo 2012 - driver door won't unlock with key but will lock

Tags: locks

I'm having an issue with my polo, the lock on the drivers door won't unlock but will lock once it's been unlocked via the passenger door using the same key. The key just spins infinately. It used to spin once or twice but eventually will unlock. Now it doesn't unlock at all.  I don't have an problems starting the car with the key either.  The switch inside the car on the drivers door works fine

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the barrel of the lock is damaged, maybe the striker for anticlockwise movement is missing or worn. [the actuator that pushes the locking mechanism back when you turn the key in the unlock direction]

Comment: Thanks for the answer even after so long. VW replaced the barrel for me since my car was still under warrenty. Perhaps I should be a little less heavy handed with my key.